# Elasticsearch - boost document based on field's specific value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a working Elasticsearch query which looks like this:

```
{
    "index": "event",
    "type": "item",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "party",
                        "type": "phrase_prefix",
                        "fuzziness": null,
                        "fields": [
                            "label^2",
                            "excerpt",
                            "body"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "is_deleted": false
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "is_private": false
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "date_start": {
                                        "gt": "now"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query searches for events which match the keyword search, are due to start in the future and filters out any marked as deleted or private.

Each user who can create an event can also buy a package to the system. I'd like to boost users whose package is of a higher value. I'm sure I need to implement a custom scoring funciton using [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), but I can't get my head around the docs and blindly trying it isn't getting me anywhere.

As an example, indexed docs might look like this:

```
[
    {
        "label": "My Birthday Party",
        "excerpt": "Come celebrate with me as I turn 30",
        "body": "I'm turning 30 soon, let's go dancing!",
        "date_start": "2016-06-19",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_private": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pablo",
            "package": {
                "id": 14,
                "cost": "1000",
                "label": "The \"£10 per month\" package"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "House Warming Party",
        "excerpt": "I moved house, help me decorate it",
        "body": "I love my new house, but it's empty and I have no furniture.",
        "date_start": "2016-04-19",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_private": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Gary",
            "package": {
                "id": 15,
                "cost": "5000",
                "label": "The \"£50 per month\" package"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

In a query which returned both of these results, how might I prioritise poor Gary (who needs help decorating) over Pablo's birthday, based on the fact that Gary's package is of a higher value (i.e. `user.package.cost`).

In an otherwise equal search, Gary's result must come first.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [script score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_script_score) to achieve this.

```
 "query": {
  "function_score": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     },
     "functions": [
        {
           "script_score": {
              "script": "_score * doc['user.package.cost'].value"

           }
        }
       ]
    }
 }
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks @richa - set me on the right track! Needed to enable [groovy] searches, but once I worked that out I got it working well.

Comment: I'm struggling to write an appropriate script which first checks if user.package exists (it can be null for a user with no package). Variations of `packageCost = doc['user.package'].value ? doc['user.package.cost'].value : 1; return packageCost * _score` give me [not so] groovy errors - any pointers?